# freestyle line out of sync 2.82.7

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

I'm having an issue if i run the animation render, after about 20-40 frames it starts to form a offset from the model lines. If I just render each frame out manually it doesn't go out of sync. I'm not exactly sure why this is happening. Has anyone ever encountered this issue before? I'm using cycles engine

[image: manually rendered]

[image: animation rendered]